# Inserting data in a foreign key table PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, insert

This is my category table. Basically there's a category and subcategory. The ParentCategoryId is the subcategory under the category. For example I have three of ParentCategoryID 1 which means it's a subcategory under category_id 1 therefore the isSubCategory is set to 1 that is saying yes it's a subcategory and 0 means it's a category that's why the parentCateogryID is null for the first four data since they are categories

[image]

I already have an Add Category functioning and now I want to have an Add Subcategory function but very confused on how I will do my usual php query.

```
<form method="POST">
            <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                include 'testdb.php';

                $addcategory = $_POST['categoryname'];
                $parentcategory = $_POST['parentcategoryID'];

                $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT categoryname FROM category WHERE categoryname = '.$addcategory.'");

                $insert = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO category (`categoryname`,`ParentCategoryID`,`isSubCategory`) VALUES ('$addcategory','$parentcategory','1')");
                if(!$insert){
                    echo mysqli_error($con);
                }
                else{
                    echo 'Category successfully added!';
                }

            }
            ?>
```

structure
[image]

whenever im trying to add.
[image]

needs to have the same id as(look pic below)[image]
this needs to be the same so the inserted sub category shows in Foods category table
[image]

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Foreign keys aren't self-referential within the same table. If your subcategories were in a different table (which I'd recommend - the above solution is really messy), then a foreign key would make it much easier for your insert functions.

Anyway, if you just wanted to add a new subcategory;

```
$addcategory = $_POST['categoryname'];
$parentcategory = $_POST['parentcategory'];

$insert = mysqli_query($con, 
"INSERT INTO category 
(`categoryname`,
`ParentCategoryID`,
`isSubCategory`)
 VALUES 
('$addcategory',
'$parentcategory'
'1')");
```

Also, consider using prepared statements.. or at least run mysqli_escape_string over the POST params you're taking in.. leaving them as they are would allow me to insert a category like '; DROP TABLE users;.

Comment: The script above should still work, as it was written with the assumption that parentcategoryid was not a foreign key.

Comment: I can't see what the table names are for that. But if you need to update an existing table based on a category ID update, you'd use an UPDATE query; http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp